# Synchronization of parent and child with SIGUSR signal in C. Make parent and child read one after the other

Tags: c, process

I have created a two way communication between parent and child processes using two pipes. Parent and child write data and I was able to make them read the data from each other. Parent writes numbers 1 to 5, and child writes numbers from 6 to 10. But I want parent to start reading data the first, and then reading continues in this order switching from parent to child until all the data are read: 6,1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5. I have tried to synchronize the reading with SIGUSR1 but when the parent is reading for the second time the program stops. I have searched a lot to find where the problem can be, and tried some tips and alike working examples, but nothing seems to help. Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void paction(int dummy)
{
   printf("P*************************************************\n");
} 

void caction(int dummy)
{
  printf("C*************************************************\n");
}

int main()
{
  int pfd[2];
  int pfd2[2];
  pid_t cfork, pfork;

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1 || pipe(pfd2) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
    exit(1);
}

cfork = fork();

signal(SIGUSR1, paction);

 if (cfork == -1) {
     printf("Fork Failed\n");
     exit(1);
  }
 else if (cfork > 0) { /*parent process*/
 int numbers[] = {1, 2,3, 4, 5};
 int numbers2[] = {  6, 7,8, 9, 10 };

 close(pfd[0]);      /*close read end, write and then close write end*/
 /*write part*/

 int limit = 5;
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
     printf("Parent sends: %d\n", numbers[i]);
     write(pfd[1], &numbers[i], sizeof(numbers[i]));

     printf("Child sends: %d\n", numbers2[i]);
     write(pfd2[1], &numbers2[i], sizeof(numbers2[i]));
   }
printf("***************************************************\n");

close(pfd[1]);
close(pfd2[1]);
/*read part/////////////////////////////////////////*/
    int temp;
    int reads = 5;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < reads; j++) {
    sleep(1);
        read(pfd2[0], &temp, sizeof(temp));
        printf("Parent gets: %d\n", temp);
    kill(cfork, SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }
 /*printf("***************************************************\n");*/
  kill( cfork, SIGUSR1 );
  close(pfd2[0]);       
}
else { /*child process*/

  signal(SIGUSR1, caction);
  close(pfd[1]);
  int temp;
  int reads = 5;
  int j;
  pfork = getppid();
    for (j = 0; j < reads; j++) {    
      sleep(1);
      read(pfd[0], &temp, sizeof(temp));
      printf("Child gets: %d\n", temp);
      kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
      pause();
    }
/*printf("***************************************************\n");*/
  close(pfd[0]);
  close(pfd2[0]);

}

return 0;
```

}

My output looks like this:

```
> Parent sends:1 
> Child sends:6 
> Parent sends:2 
> Child sends:7 
> Parent sends:3 
> Child sends:8 
> Parent sends:4 
> Child sends:9 
> Parent sends:5
> Child sends:10
> ************************************************************** 
  Parent gets:6
> C************************************************************
> Child gets:1
> P************************************************************* 
> Parent gets:7
```

And here is when it stops.
If someone can help me I would really appreciate it because I really want to know where the problem is, and since I am a beginner in C programming and processes!
Thank you in advance

Comment: "stops" meaning that it terminates, or that it hangs?

Comment: My guess is that the signal you are sending to the parent intended to wake it out of the `pause` is instead waking it from the `sleep`.  Just remove the sleeps.

Comment: As it is, it hangs. If I remove the sleeps it stops(terminates) after outputing 6.

Comment: Perhaps the child is getting SIGUSR1 before it sets the handler.  Ignore the signal pre-fork.  (But, really, using signals for synchronization is a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is not an async-safe function. Calling `printf()` in both normal code and a signal handler will cause undefined behavior. In particular, `printf()` may need to take a lock on the output-stream, while taking locks in signal-handlers is *very* inadvisable (risk of self-deadlock).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bad idea to use signals, but I had a task in which it was assigned to use SIGUSR1. I solved the issue by adding:

```
static struct sigaction pact, cact;  
/* set SIGUSR1 action for parent */;
pact.sa_handler = p_action;
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &pact, NULL);
```

After the parent was assigned the first action, it worked fine.

Thank you:)